# Dynamic variables in passenger directives with nginx

Tags: ruby, nginx, passenger

I am trying to pass nginx variables to the `passenger_app_env` or `passenger_user` directives. It seems as though Passenger is not interpolating these as I'm seeing a literal `$remote_user` getting passed through.

```
location / {
    set $something "something";
...    
    passenger_app_env $something;
...
}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: No, see https://github.com/phusion/passenger/issues/1779#issuecomment-361608171
Looks like this feature is missing in Passenger. I'm going to look at fixing it and submitting a PR.

Comment: thanks bro, if you need help let me know.

Comment: @AhmadAl-kheat i do :) I don't know C. Just fumbling around in the dark here.